# issue with setCapture() in js

Tags: javascript

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mouse Capture</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
function action() {
if (event.srcElement.id=='DIV1') DIV1.releaseCapture();
else DIV1.style.backgroundColor=Math.floor(Math.random()*16777216);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="DIV1.setCapture();">
<DIV ID="DIV1" onclick="action();" STYLE="position:absolute;top:10;left:10;height:100;width:200;background-color:red">
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Above code is taken from: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/advanced-javascript-event-handling.html

Question:

I tried it in IE, I clicked certain area(not DIV1), the color got changed, I clicked again, the color did not change, it seems that the color only can change one time, why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is changed code that change color every time you click outside the DIV, I moved to onclick to body.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mouse Capture</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
function action() {
    if (event.srcElement.id=='DIV1') {
        DIV1.releaseCapture(); 
    }
    else {
        DIV1.style.backgroundColor=Math.floor(Math.random()*16777216);
    }
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="DIV1.setCapture();" onclick="action();">
<DIV ID="DIV1"  STYLE="position:absolute;top:10;left:10;height:100;width:200;background-color:red" >
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is another alternative, with simpler code and works on Google Chrome too

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mouse Capture</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
function action() {
    if (event.srcElement.id != 'DIV1') {
        document.getElementById('DIV1').style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();
    }
}

function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY  onclick="action();">
<DIV ID="DIV1"  STYLE="position:absolute;top:10;left:10;height:100;width:200;background-color:red" >
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: well, my question is: why color only can be changed one time if I click outside the div? U can try to click multiple times outside the div, see what happen.